# Cloudfront - why is this not being "browser cached"?

Tags: caching, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

Here's the `curl -I` response to my Javascript file:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Type: text/javascript
    Content-Length: 72640
    Connection: keep-alive
    Date: Sat, 18 Feb 2017 16:12:06 GMT
    Cache-Control: 86400
    Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Feb 2017 15:09:28 GMT
    ETag: "a6ee06ff5e49a4290bb2aabe5e0f9029"
    Server: AmazonS3
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    Age: 1173
    X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
    Via: 1.1 3b17302562f1709d8b6c9f7be1.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
```

I can see the `Cache-Control` tag there. Not sure what the `Vary` and the `ETag` are doing, but so be it. Does this somehow specify to a user's browser NOT to cache this file? Why are Pingdom or Goog PageSpeed not recognising this as a browser-cacheable file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Cache-Control` header is present, but the value is not actually valid.  The correct format looks like this:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
```

The number, by itself, is meaningless.

---

`ETag:` is the entity tag -- an opaque value that uniquely identifies the current content of a given URL.  If the content changes, the ETag will also change.  A browser with a cached copy *may* use this value for subsequent requests to ask that the server only return the content if it differs, by sending an `If-None-Match:` request header, including the last-seen ETag.

`Vary:` tells the browser that certain changes to the request may generate a different response.  Unlike browsers, curl doesn't advertise its ability to support gzipped payload unless you specify the `--compressed` option.  Adding that option when invoking curl triggers the addition of `Accept-Encoding: gzip` to the request, which *may* trigger the response to be compressed if you have that option enabled in CloudFront.

Comment: That was it. My Ray Charles moment. Thank you!

Comment: Also +1 for the very lucid explanation of Etag and Vary.